# how to initialize PostgreSQL database in openshift only once

Tags: postgresql, openshift

Inorder to deploy my flask postgresql based app, i want to initialize my database with few items. Hence i created a manage.py for this. This is because i want to enter item  into database only once. After that, i want to go as usual(git push my project). 
My project works fine, problem is i don't know where should i place my manage.py and how do i use it as an admin or make sure it just run once.
I use manage.py as 
python manage.py create_tables.

this is my wsgi folder:

```
├── application
├── app.py
├── auth.py
├── flaskapp.cfg
├── forms.py
├── main.py
├── models.py
├── result.json
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── evaluate.html
│   └── show_all.html
└── views.py
```

and this is my project folder :

```
manage.py  readme.md  requirements.txt  setup.py  venv  wsgi  wsgi.py
```

Obviously, i want to initialize database in such a way that everytime i change code and push, i don't want to re-initialize the database with same entries but only when i want to and also, as an admin.

This is my application file looks like :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
# 

from main import app as application
from main import *
db.create_all()
```

The application file in openshift isn't documented well and its not clear as to what's the right place to do one time database initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code under .openshift/action_hooks in deploy file:

```
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate
python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/manage.py
```

This script will run manage.py every time that you deploy your app.

Comment: i moved my manage.py to wsgi folder and login in manually to ssh and went to wsgi folder and issued the command `python manage.py create_tables` from there. Is that okay? or should i just add just add same command into action_hooks file as you mentioned above.

Comment: also, if your above command runs everytime on deploy, that's not solves the purpose. because app is deployed in openshift every-time i do a git push. If you do a small change in code, does that mean deployment or just update?

Comment: it's ok but you must run source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate to activate virtenv             python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/manage.pycreate_tables will create table if not exist(just update)

Comment: that's already being taken care by 'application'. No? I mean enabling virtual env `#!/usr/bin/python
import os
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
# 

from main import app as application
from main import *
db.create_all()`

Comment: the problem that if you made change in your tables (locally) it will not apply in the tables in openshift because  it"s already exist you must add same commandes in deploy to pass that